# Inline 3 elements

Tags: html, css

I want to have inline form with 3 elements, 
Label Select Input 
Let me show you image, first one is what I got now, second one is what I'd like to achieve

[image]

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="input-group input-group-sm form-inline panel">
        <span class="input-group-addon">Ulica</span>
        <select ng-model="model.streetType" class="form-control" ng-options="value for (key, value) in streetTypeMap" style="width: 10%;">
                <option style="display:none"/>
            </select> 
        <input type="text" ng-model="model.street" class="form-control" placeholder="Ulica"> </input>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas how to fix that?

edit#
adding css

```
.input-group{width: 100%;}
.input-group-addon{width: 220px !important;}
```

Comment: Post your css too

Comment: Can you provide the css please ? Because only with the HTML it works fine, but the css might be changed to fix your problem

Comment: inputs don't need a closing tag, but it looks as if they are already inline - you just need to reduce the width of the input - as you use bootstrap3, you can set the width to auto: https://www.bootply.com/PLRwGlTSi2.  If you upgrade to bootstrap4, they will automatically be on one row

Comment: @jwebb Looks like Bootstrap to me

Comment: You are answering your own question in the title (use `display:inline-block`).

Comment: bootstrap form-inline class show controls in a line. or we can say In an "inline form", all of the elements are inline, left-aligned, and the labels are alongside.

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the size by the class like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="input-group input-group-sm form-inline panel">
        <span class="input-group-addon col-sm-4">Ulica</span>
        <select ng-model="model.streetType" class="form-control col-sm-2" ng-options="value for (key, value) in streetTypeMap" style="width: 10%;">
            <option style="display:none"/>
        </select> 
        <input type="text" ng-model="model.street" class="form-control col-sm-6" placeholder="Ulica"> </input>
    </div>
</div>
```